# PHP code to remove /mobile from line

Tags: php, mobile, rel

I am using rel alternate attributes on my Main site, UK site and Australia site, but it won't work on my mobile site because i need to remove the /mobile from the line,

My Mobile directory is:
www.URL.com/mobile/

When i put in this code:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.URL.co.uk<?php echo parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],PHP_URL_PATH); ?>" hreflang="en-uk" />
```

It shows as www.URL.co.uk/mobile/category-honda.html
I need it to show www.URL.co.uk/category-honda.html

How to remove

```
/mobile
```

Any help Thanks

Comment: assign your <a></a> to the $str variable
$str='<a .....</a>';

Comment: I really don't know how. Would you be so kind and post the correct 3 lines to pastebin for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$link ='http://www.URL.co.uk'.parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],PHP_URL_PATH); 
$link = str_replace('mobile', '', $link);
?>
<link rel="alternate" href="<?php echo  $link; ?>" hreflang="en-uk" />
```

Here you go, Stephen.

Comment: i clicked the green arrow, sorry real noob, just signed up.